# Struts2 / Struts1 action multiple calls

Tags: java, plugins, struts2, struts-1

I am migrating to Struts2 from Struts1 framework by using "struts2-struts1-plugin-2.3.34" with an XML based configuration.

In Struts 1 Plugin, we need to call multiple actions written in a single Action class as in Struts 1 that was identified by parameter method as follows`<action path="/list" type="com.manager.MyAction" name="list" scope="session" parameter="method" validate="false">`

Is there any way to accomodate multiple methods in Single Action? while struts2 action tag attribute "method" not supported in plugin

```
<action name="actionName" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action"> 
<param name="className">com.test.MyActionClass</param> 
<result name="success">/result.jsp</result>
```

Comment: This is not possible because the struts 1 plugin could not support method attribute in action tag so it throws "Struts has detected an unhandled exception"

Comment: S1 plugin allows to use S1 action classes as is by creating S2 configuration, but this configuration is no more than overhead to the existed configuration. Finally S1 plugin is removed from the latest Struts version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the limitation of the struts plugin that you are using. (struts2-struts1-plugin-2.3.34)

Simple work around for it is that add your form bean attributes directly to your ACTION class and make your life easier using dynamic method invocation.

Struts-1 makes use of form beans where as Struts-2 uses action stacks.

[Click here for reference to Struts 2 Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Action+Configuration#ActionConfiguration-DynamicMethodInvocation)